# Create Windows 2012 failover cluster with different networks

Tags: windows-server-2012, failovercluster

I have two servers in different networks, one in USA and another in Germany.
Can I put together in a failover cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no issue. you can also have SQL Server AG as well. Make sure you have the firewalls opened properly between these two servers. And also you need to have a common DNS/AD for the failover cluster to work. Also have a 3rd server or cluster disk for quorum or common data files.